# AspectJ load-time weaving + Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE + Tomcat 7 not working

Tags: java, tomcat, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I am trying to figure out why load-time weaving is not working yet for my web application. For my normal application (not webapp) it is working.

The test-project can be found on github (github/peterbollen/helloLtw): helloLtwAspect

When I start the application, the logs show that the load-time weaver is working ([view log](http://pastebin.com/YXgAP2uh)).
But when I trigger EchoServlet, the EchoAspect is not getting woven in ([view log](http://pastebin.com/tYTK42iW)).

Does anyone have an idea? Feel free to check out the code and try yourself (I tested the README :)) Thanks for any advice ;-)

**UPDATE 1**

Load-time weaving is working when using javaagent aspectjweaver instead of spring-instrument.

Why? Do a search for "Load-Time-Weaving differences between aspectj-weaver and spring-weaver".  I can't paste the link (not enough credits :-)).

**UPDATE 2**

Updated the github code too.

Comment: Are you using eclipse ? do you have AJDT plugin installed ? it's a must have in order to use AspectJ with Spring as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE to run the webapp. I run it using the commandline. The actual can be found at [link](https://github.com/peterbollen/helloLtw/blob/master/helloLtwAspect/README.txt)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in how tomcat 7 supports servlets 3.0 which causes Load Time Weaving to totally beak, details and work around are located at the URLS below.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7440
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52549
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52444